# What are the magic command keys to modify AWS Glue job script path and file name?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

Using just one account, I should manage three statements dev, qa, prod.
The project needs to use AWS Glue Notebooks (ipynb). But I can't modify job details in AWS Glue Notebooks UI.

They says, "JobConfig fields are controlled by notebook configuration magics. If you want to change any of these fields use the appropiate **%magic** in your notebook."

So, I tried to modify some properties like "Requested number of workers" and "Maximum concurrency" as below

```py
%%configure
{
    "number_of_workers": 6,
    "max_concurrent_runs": 6
}
```

I checked the modified values, But I can't find how to modify "Script Path", "temporary path" and "Script filename". There is no reference to modify those...

First of all, is it possible to modify it?

If it is, what are the keys for script path and script filename in magic configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add code block for glue job configuration as below

```py
%%configure
{
    "script_location": "s3://S3-ASSETS_NAME/scripts/",
    "--TempDir": "s3://S3-ASSETS_NAME/temporary/"
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).